# is there a way to make onClick hanlder on a bar on Nivo charts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, nivo-react

I'm new to Nivo.rocks, a react based charts library. Im trying to add a click handler to a bar to just console.log the data on that bar. currently the component comes with its own 'tool tip' that shows this data when you hover over a bar but i dont want that.

I've looked  at the documentation but it doesnt show how to do this clearly, is it even possible?
so far I've made a button that logs out the data from both of the bars

The main code is identical to this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nivo-0xy2m?file=/src/index.js

My button:

```
const clickHandler = () =>{
    console.log(
        `all the people that disagreed for ${data[0].statement} = ${data[0].disagree}`
    )
}
```

Comment: So you want to make a custom tooltip ? disable the tooltip ? or show the log when you click on the bar ?

Comment: Hi, I want to show the log of that specific bar when I click it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `onClick` props :

```js
onClick={(data) => {
    console.log(
    `all the people that ${data["id"]} for ${data["key"]} = ${data["value"]}`
    );
}}
```

[sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nivo-bar-clicked-ewtks?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thank you so much! my only question is, how would I make this a stand alone function, im still new to React so im confused. Say i wanted a separate click handler ?

Comment: @ShuibAbdillahi you're welcome, what do you mean by separate click handler ?

Comment: @ShuibAbdillahi you can pass a function to the `onClick` props if that's your question

Comment: for example : const clickHandler = () =>{
      
  console.log(
      `all the people that ${data['id']} for ${data['key']} = ${data['value']}`
      

  )

}.  this doesnt work

Comment: @ShuibAbdillahi you would put `clickHandler` like `onClick={clickHandler}`

Comment: ill show you more context, im basically trying to create a p tag out of this information, this is what i have :       onClick={(data) => {
          
          return(
            <p>{`all the people that ${data["id"]} for ${data["key"]} = ${data["value"]}`}</p>
          ) 
       
}}

Comment: @ShuibAbdillahi maybe update your original sandbox ?

Comment: sure, its here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nivo-forked-d0zoq?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @ShuibAbdillahi maybe the code wasn't saved, I don't see mention of click handler function ?

Comment: oh sorry! try this : https://codesandbox.io/s/nivo-forked-d0zoq?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @ShuibAbdillahi in fact you want to display a tooltip ?

Comment: well not a tooltip per say, more of a static html element like a card or something that will stay and not move away

Comment: @ShuibAbdillahi I've updated the sandbox, you can update the state in the click handler in order to update text from other component.

Comment: You're  Star! Thank you for the fast responses !